# facebook credentials instead of access token

Tags: python, facebook, python-3.x

I am new in coding and I am using this code:

```
import requests
url = (
      "https://graph.facebook.com/{album_id}/"
      "photos?access_token={access_token}"
  ).format(
      album_id= "ALBUM ID HERE",
      access_token= "PUT HERE ACCESS TOKEN" )
files = {'file': open('C:\\Users\\Leonardo\\Desktop\\black_background_texture_86812_1024x1024.jpg', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

to upload an image from a pc's folder to an album on a facebook page using an access token. How can I do the same thing using facebook credentials and page name instead of access token? I have already tried to look inside facebook SDK documentation and pythonforfacebook documentation but I can't understand how to use codes made for PHP or JAVA or IOS with python. Thanks

Comment: You can't. You have to us an access token.

Comment: Probably I haven't explained well the problem: using this code I can only publish on my facebook page with my page access token. How can I publish to another person's facebook page with the page's owner consent?

Comment: You want to post as your page or their page on their page?

Comment: As their page please

Comment: Then you have them login to your app. Grant you manage_pages and publish_pages permission. You do a request to /me/request and you get the page access token. And then you use that to post on their page

Comment: How can I do this with python?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? And what have you tried?

Comment: In the documentation they only talk about PHP, Java, IOS and android. I can't read anything about python

Comment: We also show what http request you need to make so you can do it in any language

Comment: I will try. Thank you

Comment: So the only way is to create a facebook app and give it publish_pages and manage_pages permission (so create a website for the facebook app, a "terms of service" page for the app, step by step instructions on how set permissions, screencast on how to set permissions,...)? All this things for a code that will be used by me and my relatives?

Comment: You need to create an app. You don't need a website. You don't need to submit it and get it approved if only people that have a role on the app will use it (just add your relatives as testers on the app)

Comment: Perfect. I will add my relatives as testers. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Use page_access_token instead of access_token then you can post that image through your page name.